# Values stay inside of array

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating a feature that shows the user specific people depending on the values they have set inside of their "firstLocation","secondLocation","thirdLocation". I'm going through all my Firebase users, filtering and pulling any accounts that match. This is the way I'm going about it

```
func fetchUser(){
    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Users").observe(.childAdded, with: {(snapshot) in
        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{
            let user = User()
            user.id = snapshot.key
            user.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)
            user.name = dictionary["name"] as! String?
            user.aboutMe = dictionary["aboutMe"] as! String?
            user.profileImageUrl = dictionary["profileImageUrl"] as! String?
            user.firstLocation = dictionary["firstLocation"] as! String?
            user.secondLocation = dictionary["secondLocation"] as! String?
            user.thirdLocation = dictionary["thirdLocation"] as! String?
            user.guiderMode = dictionary["guiderMode"] as! String?
            self.users =  self.users.filter{(($0.firstLocation?.contains(self.passedLocation!))!)&&$0.guiderMode == "True" || (($0.secondLocation?.contains(self.passedLocation!))!) || (($0.thirdLocation?.contains(self.passedLocation!))!)}
            self.users.append(user)
            print("The count of the users", self.users.count as Any)

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }, withCancel:nil)
}
```

The problem now is that for some reason one value always shows up even though it shouldn't be seen since it doesn't meet the filter requirements. I tried fixing it by doing

```
users.removeAll()
tableView.reloadData()
```

But it still shows up no matter what

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at self.users.append(user).  You are always appending a new user without applying a filter to it so users is always going to have at least 1 element after the observe callback gets called.

Comment: That's exactly the issue that i'm having. So should I remove the self.users.append(user) ?

Comment: My assumption is it should go before the filter.  You add the new object to the array and then filter the array so it only contains what is supposed to be there.  Thats not really the most efficient way to do it, but it should at least be correct.